# Is XCode 5 done?

Tags: ios, xcode5

Apple sent an e-mail saying to get the GM seed of Xcode 5 to get going on iOS 7 and A7 64bit changes for your apps.  The [website](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php) says it's a "Developer Preview".  Since my project is not yet in the market place, I would prefer to wait for a final version of Xcode 5 and the iOS 7 SDK.  Is that what a "GM seed" is?  And is the linked website the place to get it?  Or are they still in some sort of pre-release mode where changes will continue to be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version is a GM build, it is pretty much the release version, but it may have a few bugs that will be fixed before actual public release. It is not made to the public, yet, so you have to have a paid developer account to get your hands on it.

Comment: I thought you have to be approved developer to begin with to download any Xcode. If not then do you know when will the public version be available? I would rather download XCode once instead of installing , 5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3 every other month

Comment: @SamBudda Its free in the Mac App Store...you only need to be a paid developer to get the pre-release software, to post your apps to the app store and to test your apps on your device or any other device

Comment: I just read that Xcode 5 GM seed and iOS 7 GM seed are pre-release seeds. When is official Xcode 5 release scheduled and are we better off waiting for it?

Comment: Yes they are still pre-releases, it is pretty much the release version. But it should be released officially with iOS 7 next wednesday. (09/18/2013) If you dont have a paid developer account, it is not worth paying 99 dollars for it a week early, but if you already have an account there is no need to wait for the official release, as it is basically the build that is going to be released to the public.

Comment: The GM is the one to use to submit apps to the app store.  The beta versions cannot be used to submit to the app store.

Comment: Okay.  I work at an iOS shop, so yes, I have a dev account.  I went ahead and installed it SxS with Xcode 4.6.3 so I can switch between the two as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version in the developer console is look like a release version (after you download it there is no 'preview' label and you can submit an ios7 version with it...)